# Sql get id where column1=value1 and column1=value2

Tags: sql, where-clause

[image]

I need to get the tour_id where the tour_types_id is 7 AND 1

So in this case (image) i need:
213,215,223,225

I feel is a simple question but i can't figure out :(

Thanks.

[EDIT] Sorry where the tour_types_id is 7 (not 5) AND 1. Pot corrected

Comment: OK, having a look at this for you... Is there a particular reason you have your table structured in this way? Are you using some sort of software that created the tables of did you create the table yourself?

Comment: I didn't create this table, i'm working on a table created by someone else

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Since you want all `tour_ids` that have `tour_types_id` 1 AND 7, you can use this:

`SELECT DISTINCT tour_id FROM tablename WHERE tour_types_id = 1 OR tour_types_id = 7 GROUP BY tour_id HAVING count(DISTINCT tour_types_id) = 2`

PREVIOUS:

Maybe you're thinking about OR? If you want to get all `tour_id` that have tour_types_id = 5 or tour_types_id = 1, you need an OR. In english, the statement means: Select all the tour_ids from the table `tablename` where `tour_types_id` is equal to 1 or equal to 5.

`SELECT tour_id FROM tablename WHERE tour_types_id = 1 OR tour_types_id = 5;`

Comment: I think the question is pretty clear that the OP intends AND, not OR. S/he put that particular word in all caps.

Comment: Hm, I looked at the table that the user uploaded, and it seemed like the only way to get the tour_ids that the user posted was to use an OR statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use the query `SELECT tour_id FROM tablename WHERE tour_types_id = 5 OR tour_types_id = 1`

with `tablename` the actual name of the table you're using.
Your question is malformed though. You do not provide enough information (tablename?)

Comment: You want `OR` not `AND` as that will only select rows where `tour_types_id` matches both values, not either.

Answer (score 0):

From the results you want, it seems you want an OR not an AND.

Answer (score 0):

Use an aggregation query with `having`:

```
select tour_id
from t
where tour_types_id in (1, 7)
group by tour_types_id
having count(distinct tour_types_id) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use in clause too after the where like

```
SELECT tour_id FROM [Table_Name] WHERE tour_type_id IN (1,5)
```

this can be more flexible for you if you want to add or remove some ids

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select tour_id 
from xxxxtable 
where tour_types_id = 1 
   OR tour_types_id = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tour_id FROM tablename t1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE tour_types_id = '1' AND tour_id = t1.tour_id) 
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE tour_types_id = '7' AND tour_id = t1.tour_id)
```

Sorry if i wasted your time, i was searching for hours.

Thanks for the help